# How is a soft-fork activation block defined?

Tags: soft-fork

Every soft-fork must have an activation block. This is also important for the consensus rules, because through that block it is defined from which point the new rules must be respected for the nodes that will be synchronized in the future and will have the latest consensus rules (take a [look](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/100388/145749)).

I'm interested in how is a soft-fork activation block determined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/97047/208

Comment: @PieterWuille It does. Just have one question. For BIP16/30 timestamp is used, for BIP34/BIP65/BIP66 block number is used, but what is used for locktime, segWit and Taproot soft-forks? I can't find it in third part of your linked answer ("*Versionbits-based signalling: BIP68/112/113, BIP141/143/144, BIP91, BIP341/342*").

Comment: @PieterWuille I am not referring to the way of signaling (BIP 9), but the way of checking in the consensus from which the given rules are applied.

Comment: That is quite literally described in BIP9.

Comment: @PieterWuille I assumed that, but I do not have a time now to read entire BIP. Never mind, thanks anyway